# LaTeX Error on BibTex

Tags: latex

I am compiling a Tex document using WinEdt, but I encountered the following problem:

> "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, (La)TeX-related questions (and solutions) are better asked at [tex.se]. I've flagged your question so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: @Alexis No need to flag, you can now close it as “off topic” and choose an appropriate migration target.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have not reached yet the 3000 rep needed to close questions... http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions

Comment: No need to flag: Downvoted. Google exists, you know.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Note that this question is the second hit on DuckDuckGo, and none of the other first-page hits even mention the issue mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this problem for quite an afternoon, and I thought I have to share this. This error will be produced if BibTeX is being used but there are no `\cite` commands in your document.